# How to make Links inside EditText not Clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-edittext

I have an EditText that contains some text and hyperlink. Whenever I click on hyperLink it opens the browser. It doesn't let me edit the link. How can I disable the click on just Hyperlinks inside EditText

Answer (score 3):

```
android:linksClickable="false"
```

Comment: Do you need the this behaviour when editing? If not I'd suggest displaying TextView with android:linksClickable="false" when editing is not active and then changing it to EditText when needed

Comment: Just done. Please see my Answer. Thanks for your time.